# Nginx static webpage and Docker with env variable url

Tags: docker, nginx, environment-variables

I've got a nginx web server with a webpage inside that makes some http calls.
I want to dockerize all and use a parametric URL.
Is there a way to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: What 's exactly your question? I don't get the parametric thing. Can you explain it in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need a dynamic web page containing a script that makes HTTP calls to a configurable URL.
That can be achieved using [Server Side Includes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html). with `nginx`. The webpage could include a configuration file that is created during the initialization of the container.

Create the file into the `nginx` document root when the image is first started. For example:

```
docker run -e URL=http://stackoverflow.com --entrypoint="/bin/sh" nginx  -c 'echo ${URL} > /usr/share/nginx/html/url_config & exec nginx -g "daemon off;"'
```

For a real world scenario create a custom image based on `nginx` and override the entrypoint. The entrypoint creates the configuration file with the URL environment variable and eventually launches `nginx` in foreground.

Include the configuration file in the web page using the `#include` SSI directive

```
<script>
...
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = '<!--#include file="url_config" -->';
http.open("GET", url);
http.send();
...
```

Configure nginx to process SSI by adding the `ssi on;` directive

```
http {
    ssi on;
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! I need something llike this. I'll try if it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible,But you can do this using docker network if you want some routing. but you can do anything with Docker. According you question title you want to use ENV in URL in the Nginx Configuration. Here is the way to do that.

- Set Environment in Docker run command or Dockerfile
- Use that Environment variable in your Nginx config file

```
    docker run --name nginx -e APP_HOST_NAME="myexample.com" -e APP_HOST_PORT="3000" yourimage_nginx
```

Now you can use these URL in your nginx configuration.

```
    server {
        set_by_lua $curr_server_name 'return os.getenv("APP_HOST_NAME")';
        set_by_lua $curr_server_port 'return os.getenv("APP_HOST_PORT")';
        proxy_pass         http://$curr_server_name/index.html;
    }
```

To deal with ENV with nginx you can check [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module)

Comment: I'm not sure it will work. My problem is that I want to reach a url from my javascript library and I want to pass this url from env variable or something similar. I put all my static website under nginx.

Comment: javascript client-side? which framework you are using?

Comment: Environment variables designed for `server-side` usage. Not for the client side. So if you want to change these in the static file it will not work.